# What can I use to generate email/pdf reports based on a steady incoming data stream?

Tags: jasper-reports, report, reporting

I have data coming in to a MySQL instance and I want to be able to analyze time-seperated data and generate a report based on that. What would be the best software/method to make use of? Would Jasper reports be of use here?

Free/open source would be preferable. The reports can go out to a number of preset emails assigned based on the data being reported on. For example, Site A which will have a report sent out every hour based on the incoming data would go out to a managed list of 4 or 5 people, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/), and specifically at the [Schedule Server](http://dbxtra.com/report-scheduler.htm) component which lets you send reports in emails automatically and unattended every certain time, although it's not free (there is a fully functional trial version however).

If you insist on it being free, i think that you can use any option you want (i prefer Jasper Reports), but you'll need to create and send the emails by hand or make a solution yourself as the option to send emails automatically it's not present on the free tiers.

P.S.: I'm a DBxtra evangelist.

Comment: Doesn't look like a bad option at all! But still a trial version :(